# Communication error

Tags: mechanism

My Robot arm and controller battery got ablated it showed H1600 mechanism error.. did ram reset of the controller but controller not seeing robot arm. it is RV-2FB-D1-SM15 Robot arm and CR750 D controller. During the ram reset it is expected the controller should recognize the robot arm but all it shows is user on the teach Pendant.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* muhammad aminu, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so please include details of what you want to understand, what you've researched so far, what you found & what you expected to find. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: You say your robot arm and controller battery got "ablated," and I'm not sure if this a translation issue or what, but I would take "got ablated" to mean "got destroyed by heat/fire." If the arm had some kind of damage to the controller and/or battery then it may never work. Regardless, there's not enough information here for us to help troubleshoot. I would *strongly recommend* you reach out to the manufacturer for support.

Comment: On stack exchange, it is better to edit your question to add information requested in comments, rather than adding more comments. Comments are for helping to improve questions and answers, and are distracting, so we try to keep them to a minimum. If all of the information needed to answer the question is contained within it, the comments can be tidied up (deleted).